# I can not call this.function: TypeError: this.fetchData is not a function

Tags: javascript, typescript

I get this error "TypeError: this.fetchData is not a function" when I call `this.fetchData();` and I thought that `this` is lost so I tried to use `bind` or arrow function but it did not work either, how to solve this ?

```
class ShowResults extends Component {
    getData() {
        return setTimeout(function() {
            this.fetchData();
          }, 2000); //tried to use bind but did not work--> .bind(this);
        }
      }

      async fetchData() {
        //code
      }
}
```

Comment: This is inside the same object, right? Does not become clear from your snippet...

Comment: Should work with bind or arrow function unless you are calling `getData` without context either

Comment: @AtulKumar No. That will not be called with context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i created an example where i'm binded using the constructor or onclick.

```
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.getData = this.getData.bind(this);
  }

  getData() {
    return setTimeout(() => {
      this.fetchData();
    }, 0) //tried to use bind but did not work--> .bind(this);
  };


  async fetchData() {
    console.log('its called');
  }
```

or

```
 <header className="App-header" onClick={this.getData.bind(this)}></header>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you said, you need `.bind(this)` because you are not in the same scope inside the setTimeout function ; could you send more code, there is something weird with your number of brackets.

Answer (score 0):

You can also call the method as follow:

`<header className="App-header" onClick={() => this.getData()}></header>`

So you don need not to bind. It does by itself.